# No such file or directory, but file is present?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to gcc the following project from Azure on Ubuntu 20.04: https://github.com/Azure/azure-umqtt-c

When I've installed the project through cmake, I attempt to gcc mqtt_client.c, but get met with the following error:

```
omic@omic-virtual-machine:~/azure-umqtt-c/src$ gcc mqtt_client.c
mqtt_client.c:18:10: fatal error: azure_umqtt_c/mqtt_client.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include <azure_umqtt_c/mqtt_client.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

However, when I go to azure-umqtt-c/inc/azure-umqtt-c, the file mqtt_client.h is present. Can someone assist me and make me understand why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Well you expect your compiler to look into the arbitrary `inc/` subdirectory for includes. How is `gcc` to know that?

You can tell GCC that you want it to look into a directory using the `-I` flag, e.g. `gcc -Iinc/ ...`.

But honestly: you don't build C code without a build system, which will set such flags correctly for you (you're missing a lot of other flags as well, this all makes little sense!). The repo you link to even tells you how to do that (the part involving `cmake`), you're just not following the instructions!

Comment: I have build it using cmake, and also installed it. I tried to use the -Iinc/azure_umqtt_c but it still doesn't work.

Comment: But if you installed it, then why does it matter that some files exist in inc/... ? Again, you still are missing a lot of flags, you will need at least a rudimentary build system to not only specify `-I`, but also linker flags and other things.

Comment: Sorry, you're confusing me even further. I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and GCC compilation, as well as using cmake etc. I will try uninstalling everything and installing it again, following the instructions once more..

Comment: Don't uninstall.

Comment: The way you are building *your* program (the mqtt_client.c) just is not how you can build a C program, usually. You need to use the *right* compiler flags. I don't know the library you're linking to, but usually an installation also sets up things that can tell build systems (e.g. CMake, meson, autoconf) what flags to include when using a library. The repo readme you linked to, again, under "installation and usage" tells you what to have in *your* CMakeLists.txt for your program to get compiled with the correct flags.

Comment: I want to use mutation testing on the file, but before I do that I just want to make sure I can actually build the file with gcc. I won't need to link any other files, I just want to mutate that single file for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135446/discussion-between-oliver-michaelsen-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: sorry, can't do chat. Nothing in your computer "cares" about that you "only" want to compile one file, you still need to do it right :) That's what CMake is for, letting you compile software correctly, using the right flags on your system for the libraries you use.

Comment: Okay but I followed all isntructions, build and installed it using cmake but still this happens.

Comment: You are building some software that uses that library ("YOUR" software). So, you will need to build *your* software using CMake, yourself. Nowhere in that chain will you call `gcc` manually. That will be done for you, correctly, whenever you ask for it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping, I will try to get it to work.

Comment: @OliverMichaelsen if, "_I've installed the project through `cmake`, I attempt to `gcc mqtt_client.c`_" then you are not following the instructions.